# Test statistics in maven surefire / junit4

Tags: spring, maven, junit, surefire

We're using the maven surefire plugin (2.14) to run our junit4 tests and all works well.

However, our application is based around Spring and each of our test classes uses SpringJUnit4ClassRunner as the @RunWith class. This means that for each test class started up the Spring Application Context will also get started, and shutdown when all tests are complete (all test classes use the @DirtiesContext annotation). So test statistics from surefire may say that a particular test class took 10 seconds to run all of its included tests when in actual fact the tests as a whole took 3 minutes from Spring start-up to shutdown. We're intending to remove this constant start-up/shutdown but we're trying to get an idea of how badly our tests are effected.

Is there any way of getting the statistics of how long the test class itself took to run as opposed to the total of the individual tests?

I thought a custom implementation of the RunListener class might be the answer but I think it only covers statistics of the individual tests, not the whole.

Comment: Ah, although the surefire xml output files contain the test method timings the plain text files that are produced have the overall time, which is what I'm after. The question now is how do I produce a report using those? The surefire report plugin appears to use the xml files as a source.

Comment: And why do the generated surefire test files (mxml and plain text) contain different timings? Shouldn't they agree?